# Повторная загрузка AssetBundle каждый раз при запуске приложения

Tags: c#, unity3d

Разбил приложение на основное и AssetBundle, подгружаю их при первом запуске.

Пользуюсь для этого следующим кодом

```
void Download(Action callback)
    {
        uwr = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle("https://MyUrl");
        uwr.SendWebRequest();
        _coroutine.StartCoroutine(CheckProgress(callback));
    }

    IEnumerator CheckProgress(Action callback)
    {
        while (!uwr.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
            Debug.LogError(uwr.downloadProgress * 100 + "%");
        }
        _bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(uwr);
        callback();
    }
```

Прогресс успешно показывается и доходит до конца, игра запускается и работает с бандлами.

Но при повторном запуске всё повторяется! Официальная документация юнити говорит что UnityWebRequest кеширует все бандлы локально и при повторном запуске обращается с ним же. Но у меня оно почему то их скачивает заново каждый раз. В чем дело, как это исправить, и как хотя бы проверить наличие бандлов на локальном устройства? Платформа - редактор и устройство Android

Comment: Судя по справке, требуется конструктор с версией - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandlerAssetBundle-ctor.html

Comment: @Monk Всё верно! Сейчас напишу полный ответ

Answer (score 1):

Использовал неправильный конструктор для кэшируемых бандлов. Вот как надо

```
void Download(Action callback)
{
    uwr = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle("https://MyUrl");

   //Вот сюда надо добавить одну строчку
    uwr.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerAssetBundle(url, 0,0);

    uwr.SendWebRequest();
    _coroutine.StartCoroutine(CheckProgress(callback));
}

IEnumerator CheckProgress(Action callback)
{
    while (!uwr.isDone)
    {
        yield return null;
        Debug.LogError(uwr.downloadProgress * 100 + "%");
    }
    _bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(uwr);
    callback();
}
```

При условии что мы игнорируем проверку версии. Иначе в аргументы нужно будет подставить вместо первого нуля  - её. При несовпадении версии бандлов они будут перекачиваться.